# Does NLog raise an event when something is logged?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I want to be able to catch this event in order to not only log the message but to insert this message into a ListView simultaneously. Is there such an event?

Comment: Not an event but target: [Memory Target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Memory-target)

Comment: If this is Winforms: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets#nlogwindowsforms-package-

Comment: Maybe this is also a possible way: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target

Comment: And last but not least, you could write your own custom target.

Comment: Great, that helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments are right, but to elaborate:

In NLog log-events aren't event-driven (there are no event handlers), but route-driven. So every event is matched to the defined routes (the `<rules>` in your nlog.config).

With the routes you can send the log-events so 0, 1 or multiple targets and create fallbacks, filtering etc.

So if you need the logevents in a ListView, you need to search for a target to use or write a custom one.

Full list of targets are here: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=targets

Writing a custom target is explained here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

Happy logging :)